# Daily update SQLite Android Datewise

Tags: android, date, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have searched here but cant get any answer related to my query.

I have used sqlite database in my android app. I have a table "dailydata". This table contains a column name date , which stores the current system date.
Now what I want is, to update the daily records DATEWISE inserted by users daily. My primary key of the table is integer auto increment.

I am trying to enter user data through this method below.

```
    public long sendupdate(boolean isdata) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(DATA_TODAY, isdata); // DATA_TODAY is my column where i need to update user value

        // return ourDatabase.update(MY_DAILYTABLE, cv , "WHERE" + DATE + "=" +
        // ( "SELECT" + "MAX(DATE)" + "FROM " + MY_DAILYTABLE), null);





            // ourDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE MY_DAILYTABLE  WHERE Date = (SELECT Max(DATE FROM  MY_DAILYTABLE ",
    // null);

        }
```

I have tried doing this from both these methods but no luck.
Can anybody guide me how to update daily records datewise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update column in database , you must pass table name , then content value (consist of key and value  as it in database )

column name that will compare with (unique value ) , this column value

make sure that  DATA_TODAY is boolean in database

this code

```
 public boolean updateData(long rowId, String name) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
  }
```

if you want update your database daily

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

// if you need current day of month 
// int DayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

day here is number , Sunday equal 1  (day=1) Monday equal 2 (day = 2) ..... Saturday equal 7 (day = 7 )

use switch to update your database

// after Edit

```
switch (day) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // call update method , put rowID , then pass the day 
    // notice that day here is integer
   // String.valueOf(day)   
     updateData(rowId, day);
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        // ...


    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        // etc ...
}
```

Comment: Hey # mina tell me one thing as I store date only once in this database , so it saved the date. I want the date to be updated daily. so how can I update DATE column to current system date.

Comment: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); then you can use switch (day) {
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        // ... here use update your database 

    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        //  ...here use update your database 
}

Comment: Thank you mina , but can you explain me this bit more? how to pass date update in database class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`writableDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);`
This will insert or update if the data already exist. THe only constraint is that the row to have a primary key;